# Do all skins have a StatTrak variant?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've heard that not all skins in CS:GO have the ability to come in as a  StatTrak . Is this true? If yes, which skins are  StatTrak able?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here're the details:

- All StatTrak skins must be obtained from a weapon case.  This means that weapon drops through normal gameplay do not have StatTrak variants.

  - This means that weapons that come from a collection that isn't from a case (*the Assault collection, the Nuke collection, the Inferno collection, etc.*) will not have StatTrak variants.
- As to why the other answer was wrong: there is no guaranteed chance at getting a StatTrak variant.  In TF2, a Strange weapon is a guaranteed Strange, but the same does not apply in CS:GO.
- Additionally, for knives (just like for guns), StatTrak variants can be unboxed.

Comment: It can also be noted that there is also a "Souvenir" variant of a skin, which can be obtained to participating or watching a tournament.

Comment: @KimMinseo And so what? The OP specifically wants to know which skins have StatTrak, not what skins have other variants

Comment: @memescientist It is an additional piece of information which is always useful.

Answer (score 1):

Skins in CS:GO can be obtained in 3 different methods:
1. Through random drops;
2. Uncrating, where you use a key to open a case, or;
3. Trading or through Steam Community Market transactions.

These skins come in 8 different qualities, namely:
1. White (Common) - Consumer grade
2. Light blue (Uncommon) - Industrial grade
3. Darker blue (Rare) - Mil-spec
4. Purple (Mythical) - Restricted
5. Pinkish purple (Legendary) - Classified
6. Red (Ancient) - Covert
7. Gold (Exceedingly Rare) - ★ Melee Weapons
8. Light Brown (Immortal) - Contraband (discontinued)

These skins also come in 3 different types (from Counter-Strike Wiki):

> In the Steam Market and in-game inventory, all general skins have a
>   white border around the preview icon, while knives are bordered with
>   Purple, the StatTrak™ weapons with Orange, Souvenir weapons with
>   Yellow, and self-made Prototype skins with Green.

The exterior quality of the skins can also differ:
1. Factory New
2. Minimal Wear
3. Field-Tested
4. Well-Worn
5. Battle-Scarred

It can be noted that StatTrak™ weapons can only come from cases, or by trading. Thus, it is impossible to get StatTrak™ weapons from drops. Skins with Souvenir type do not also have StatTrak™ variations.

For a complete list of skins without StatTrak™ variations, visit this website:
[List of CS:GO Skins](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Skins/List)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @memescientist I gave him a website which leads to the complete list, which is more than you did.

Comment: @KimMinseo And if that site was to go down, your answer would not answer the question. This is why we're against link-only answers here.

Comment: While I think your answer provides more information about the item asked about...they're right that you're not actually answering the question outside of the link.  I'd highly recommend either answering the question, or summarizing the information contained at the link.

Comment: There are just too many skins without StatTrak variant and not all of them fall into the same category. The other informations were to help the OP get the basic background behind the skins.